# expression must have (pointer-to-) function type

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Objective : this code calculate the distances between numbers(every number is a location of any city) i was written the code but when i use the "min" function included in "algorithm" library the " expression must have  (pointer-to-) function type  " error will occur.

this is a code :

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int noc, ele, min, max,arr[100];

    cin >> noc;

    for(int i = 0;i < noc;i++)
        cin >> arr[i];



    for(int i = 0;i < noc;i++){
        if(i == 0)
            cout << abs(arr[0] - arr[1]) << "  " << abs(arr[0] - arr[noc - 1]) << endl;
        else if(i == noc - 1)
            cout << abs(arr[noc - 1] - arr[noc - 2]) << "  " << abs(arr[noc - 1] - arr[0]);
        else{
            min(4 ,5 ,6);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues:

The variable called `min` shadows the function in the `std` namespace. You should generally not write `using namespace std;` for exactly this reason.

`std::min` doesn't take three arguments to return the smallest, just two. You can chain calls to it, or in C++11 you can use the initializer-list overload:

```
std::min(std::min(4,5),6);
//or
std::min({4,5,6});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have also used `min` as a variable name, and since you have put all symbols from the `std` namespace in the global namespace with `using namespace std`, you think that you can use `min` without prefixing it with `std::`.
But because there is also a local variable called min, that takes precedence.

tldr: Don't use `using namespace std`, and don't name local variables like global functions.